# getElementsByTag not working

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

Hi so I have a XML document in a folder on my desktop, I am trying to read out all the elements with the tag name "cuisine".

Here is my code:

```js
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send()
xmlData = xmlhttp.responseXML;

cuisineList = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("cuisine");
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = cuisineList.length;
```

When I print out the length of the `cuisineList` it says its zero.

Here is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding"ISO-8859-1"?>
<food>
    <cuisine type="Chinese">
    </cuisine>
    <cuisine type="Indian">

    </cuisine>
</food>
```

Comment: Is the request succeeding? If you're running it locally, it should result in a security error.

Comment: You should move your document to your development server. Javascript can't access documents in your desktop folder.

Comment: What does the console have to say? Is it reading  the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error in your document (there is a missing '=' in the encoding attribute).